# Is there a Razor c# command equivalent to PHP's "die"?

Tags: c#, php, razor

My google-foo has turned up nothing.
A command like this would be handy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`HttpResponse.End`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end(v=vs.110).aspx). However I'd consider it code smell. Very stinky code smell. Try to avoid it if you can.

Comment: Yes I consider php die to be a bad code smell too. Even more so in razor with layout templating but it still has its edge case uses. Thank you.